# Patching Categorical quotient of Toric varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am studying Cox's 'The Homogeneous Coordinate Ring of a Toric Variety' paper, and looking at the proof of theorem 2.1.

Towards the end of the proof of part (i) we have gathered a collection of good catagorical quotients
$U_\sigma/G \cong X_\sigma$. The paper then states that these quotients patch together in the same way that these would in the local construction.
A result in the cox, little, schenck book (Prop 5.0.12) gives a similar idea. I'm failing to understand how this 'patching' works. In the local construction there is an extra 'gluing' step that doesn't seem to be prescent here. I understand that the $X_\sigma$ give an open cover of $X_\Sigma$ but arent they only equal when the union is disjoint and the gluing procedure has taken place?

Appologies, I know this is very specific.